# why is Firestore fail to load collections and gives errors?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase cloud function to write on firestore.
 when I try to add this hierarchy :

```
/Users/eg3LxyXQTxOsYCimyP1cf7YOYzm2/MyAds/1DZ2USCMs0ARQ3YfZb5l/
```

it is added perfectly on the database But what I want is this

```
/Users/{randomid}/MyAds/{randomId}/photos/{id}/
```

But it gives *Error loading collections* on firestore
[image: error during loading collections]
I really don't know what is the problem in my code because it works for the first hierarchy.

this is my code which when executed gives the error :

```
 return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(id).collection('MyAds').doc(mySubString).collection('photos')
    .doc().set(
    {imageUrl :xx},
    {merge:true}
    );
```

**NOTE**: when I try it manually , **IT WORKS**

Do someOne know why I am facing this error and How to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like a temporary problem with the console.  If you're having a problem with the Firebase console, contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I faced this problem 2 dayes ago .Ok I contacted them right now and this is the answer :Hello there,
Our autoresponder is broken, and we’re working on fixing it now. We’ve received your support case and will follow up soon. 
Thanks,
Darwin
Firebase Support

Comment: It's currently winter holiday season through much of Google. You might have to wait a few days.

Comment: Where does *{randomid}* and *mySubString* come from? If those are nil, it will error as you described.

Comment: no it is just abbreviations for jhgkfuktthr and rsdujyfg random keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have disabled my Ad Block and It is now showing all the data correctly .